# How to access files stored with App Engine app

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have a problem with including `countries.xml` file to my GWT web application.

On app server-side I gather data from this file by using `JAXB`. Everything works fine on local build from eclipse but after deploy to test environment Unmarshaller can't find mentioned file.

I don't think the file was included at all durning deploy.

The question is: where I should place the xml file to successfully be included in application deploy?

If there's some information missing, please, let me know i comments.

**EDIT1:**

[image]

Loading the file:

```
    List<CountryDTO> list = new ArrayList<CountryDTO>();
    CountryXML countryXML;
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CountryXML.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        countryXML = (CountryXML) un.unmarshal(new File("target/classes/server/xml/countries.xml"));
        for (CountryXML country : countryXML.getCountries()) {
            list.add(convertToDTO(country)); //Simple converting from XmlRootObject to DTO
        }
    }
    catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JUnit test:

```
public class XMLDataManagerTest {

    @Test
    public void getCountries() {
        XMLDataManager xmlDataManager = new XMLDataManager();
        List<CountryDTO> coutries = xmlDataManager.getCountries();
        System.out.println(coutries.toString());
    }

}
```

And the output from this test is what I wanted it to be.

Comment: Where is the file countries.xml stored? Please post the code that loads the file.

Comment: Why do you specify target/classes, /server/xml/countries.xml should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**, as follows:

- moved `countries.xml` to WEB-module, path: `src/main/webapp/resources/countires.xml`

Code sample:

- in servlet:

  ```
      URL countriesXMLURL = this.getServletContext().getResource("/resources/countries.xml")
  ```
- in XML manager with JAXB:

  ```
      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CountryXML.class);
      Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
      countryXML = (CountryXML) un.unmarshal(countriesXMLURL);
  ```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I believe that the file was successfully uploaded. Anyway, you can check it by downloading your app from App Engine.

```
./appcfg.sh -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> download_app <output-dir>
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application).

It seems that the app layout is different in local environment and in the cloud. Try to load your file by means of `ClassLoader`.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/server/xml/countries.xml");
```

Or by means of `ServletContext`.

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/server/xml/countries.xml");
```

You can also check my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873574/reading-a-file-from-within-app-engine-module) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892531/3029175).

It seems that preferred solution for App Engine is via `ServletContext`.

> App Engine resource files are read using `java.io.File` or
>   `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResource/getResourceAsStream`. They are
>   not accessible via `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Even if i got the file as Stream, how am I supposed to use it in JAXB?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question. Just pass the given `InpustStream` instead of `File` to `unmarshal()` method. See [Unmarshaller#unmarshal(InputSource)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(org.xml.sax.InputSource)).

Comment: Sorry, incorrect link. See [Unmarshaller#unmarshal(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: Stupid question, indeed. Thought there isn't method with Stream parameter. Gonna check this out now.

Comment: I'm getting NPE while trying to use Unmarshaller with this Stream as parameter. So it isn't working.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting NPE? Check first that the file has been successfully loaded (e.g. write the content of the stream to the log). Are you using `ServletContext` or `ClassLoader`?

Comment: And one more thing. Use slash at the beginning of the path and check that your path is correct.

Comment: I'm getting `NPE` at `AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java unmarshal 199` exactly. I'm pretty sure that there isn't this xml file on cloud uploaded... I'm using ServletContext. I've tried `"/server/xml/countries.xml"` and `"server/xml/countries.xml"` versions of path, but it ain't work.

Comment: I've also tried to log InputStream content but one more time got NPE at log line of code so I'm pretty sure that this file doesn't exists or exists on other file path. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `ServletContext` to access the resource file? See my updated answer. You may download the app from App Engine to check the file is there and the correct path.

Comment: Yup. I think the best solution is to add this file to the package where my Servlet belongs. But what path should I use in this case?

Comment: It should work even if the file is stored in the resource folder. Build your project via maven (`mv clean install`) and post path to the file in your target directory.

Comment: I can't find this xml file in builded war, even using my OS searching tool.

Comment: Can you share your project somewhere (e.g. GitHub) so that I can look at it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's company product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104173/discussion-between-pgiecek-and-hubert-popiolkiewicz).